# Pipe between 2 child processes UNIX C

Tags: c, parsing, shell, unix, pipe

I was creating a pipe between 2 child processes. One would output to the pipe, and the other would input from the pipe. I was able to parse the command and parameters required to execute a command (or 2 since its a pipe). However, I think my pipe is setup incorrectly:

```
[...] 
type_prompt(); //Type out prompt to the user
read_command(); //Read the command from the user

pipe(&fd[0]); //Create a pipe
proc1 = fork();

//Child process 1
if (proc1 == 0)
{
close(fd[0]); //process1 doenst need to read from pipe
dup2(fd[1], STD_INPUT);
close(fd[1]);
execvp(parameter[0], parameter); //Execute the process
}

//Create a second child process
else
{
//Child process 2
proc2 = fork();
if (proc2 == 0)
{
close(fd[1]);
dup2(fd[0], STD_OUTPUT);
close(fd[0]);
execvp(parameter2[0], parameter2);
}
//Parent process
else
{
waitpid(-1, &status, 0); //Wait for the child to be done
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the getline() function from? If it is the one from GCC, you are supposed to use a dynamically allocated buffer with it.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a pointer to a buffer allocated with `malloc` as the first argument to `getline`, for example:

```
  int bytes_read;
  int nbytes = 100;
  char *my_string;

  /* These 2 lines are the heart of the program. */
  my_string = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
  bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);
```

See http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html for more details (the above example is taken from there and reduced).